# Wordpress Plugin. Where should I save my simple cache?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a little plugin to access the Instagram API for one account with some simple custom methods. I am curious as to how/where one should save this type of cache within the Wordpress system to be standard? (i.e. Flat file, stored in X location with other cache files.)

Standalone, I would probably use a flat file to store the cache being it will only be updated periodically and only pulls a few posts from one account. But perhaps there is a good way to use Wordpress to store this data to the DB. Either way I am not sure where this should be located within Wordpress's DB or file structure. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053394/php-caching-is-it-faster-to-save-in-database-or-create-a-file

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like a file is better, now to learn if there is a good place to store that cache in the WP file structure.